# Problem with visual basic 2022 and crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2022

I just installed  visual basic 2022 and i wanted to know what do i need to run crystal report on it
cause i was using visual basic 2013 and all the projects that contain crystal reports  giving errors and i can't even find crystal reports in references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports integration with Visual Studio is no longer automatic. It requires a separate download. For full details, see this SAP wiki: [Crystal Reports, Developer for Visual Studio Downloads](https://help.sap.com/docs/SUPPORT_CONTENT/crystalreports/3354091173.html)